Python API Request Response Returns a 401 Unathorized but Works in Curl
I'm running into a 401 error when trying to post data. However, the same data entered in a curl request works just fine. I have tried multiple attempts at trying get a 201 or 200 response.
import requests
import arubaapi
import json
import getpass
import urllib3
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

urllib3.disable_warnings()

dummyUsernam = input("Please enter your username: ")
print("\n")
dummyPassword = getpass.getpass("please enter your password: ")
print("\n") 


aosDeviceFqdn = 'sjc04-wwi-mm-node1.mine.com'

def aosLogin():

    #dummyUsernam = input("Please enter your username: ")
    #print("\n")
    #dummyPassword = getpass.getpass("please enter your password: ")
    #print("\n")

    """Logs into the AOS device, returns <class requests.Session()> object and UID string"""

    session = requests.Session()

    myUrl = f'https://{aosDeviceFqdn}:4343/v1/api/login'
    credentials = {
        'username': dummyUsernam,
        'password': dummyPassword,
    }

#try:
#loginResponse = session.get( url=myUrl, params=credentials, verify=False )
    loginResponse = session.post( url=myUrl, data=credentials, verify=False ) # same result

#except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
    #print(f"Failed to reach {aosDeviceFqdn}, check that you are connected to VPN and that {aosDeviceFqdn} resolves properly in DNS")
    #exit()

#except KeyError:
    #print ("Please check the username and password, and that your account has permission to log in and is not locked.")
    #exit()

    jsonLoginResponse = loginResponse.json()
    arubaUid1 = jsonLoginResponse['_global_result'] # this method of retrieving the UID is only available in the response of the login action
#arubaUid2 = getUidFromSession(session) # this is the same result as arubaUid1, extracted a different way, available anytime an open, logged-in session exists
    global sub
    sub = arubaUid1.get("UIDARUBA")

    print(sub)
    return sub

def func_2():
    myUrl1 = ('https://sjc04-wwi-mm-node1.mine.com:4343/v1/configuration/object/airmatch_ap_freeze?config_path=%2Fmd%2FTesla-Workplace%2FSJC51')
    myHeaders1 = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json'}
    myParams1 = {'UIDARUBA': sub}

# shut
    myData1 = r'{ "ap-name":"sjc51-api-5m-10" , "channel":"104-" ,  "band_info":"5GHz" }'
    response = requests.post(url=myUrl1, headers=myHeaders1, params=myParams1,  data=myData1, verify=False)
    print(response)
#return sub

aosLogin()
func_2()
############End of Code#########
output:
Desktop % python3 start_over_api_call.py
Please enter your username: myusername


please enter your password: 


NzI1MDBmMmItYjg0Mi00MGJjLTkwODctZGU0
<Response [401]>

Can anyone help identify what the issue could be? Ideally my account and creds are authorized as it works in Curl. I feel like the session is closing and the token is being rendered as expired.

Can you please provide a URL along with headers and data that is working with cURL and can you specifically highlight the same in your code? You're asking the reader to find where the issue is.

#Working url = https://sjc04-wwi-mm-node1.mine.com:4343/v1/api/login #Working headers = --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Accept:application/json"

Its almost as if the server is not trusting the token which is coming from the same device and session.
